# Moving row down or up manually in attribute table of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3

I have digitized several lines in ArcMap and I did not pay any attention to ordering it initially only to realize later that I need to other them somehow not according to any of the columns.

Is there a way to manually re-order the rows?

I have tried doing it in editor mode and outside it but did not work.

Comment: Usually, the order of records in an ArcGIS database is unspecified. Depending on the type of database, you don't even get to see them in order of creation, so deleting/adding some record won't always help you. If order is relevant to you, you'd have to add a field to sort on.

Comment: @Berend I think you should add that last sentence with just a little expansion as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArcGIS currently does not support manual ordering so What I have had to do is create a new column called "order" and number the rows in the order that I want. Quite tedious work for 90 plus rows.

Comment: I think you would have also needed to Sort the table permanently on that column.

Comment: Yeah that's right @PolyGeo